# Unable to cast NSMutableDictionnary as [String: AnyObject]

Tags: swift2

I am moving to Swift 2.1 some code that was managing persistency CoreData. Though I get a strange error telling me that I can't cast `NSMutableDictionnary` to `[String: AnyObject]` which is something I don't understand

```
do {
    try coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType,
        configuration: nil, URL: url, options: options)
} catch var providedError as NSError {
    coordinator = nil
    // Report any error we got.
    let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
    dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
    dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
    dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = providedError

    let error = NSError(domain: "SOME_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999,
        userInfo: dict as! [String : AnyObject]) // <--- HERE IS THE WARNING
} catch {
    fatalError()
}
```

The warning message:

`Cast from 'NSMutableDictionary' to unrelated type '[String : AnyObject]' always fails`

I will workaround this by using directly a Swift Dictionnary but I would like to get the why of such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the code suggested by Apple in the Core Data template.

```
let dict = [String: AnyObject]()
dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = providedError

let error = NSError(domain: "SOME_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
```

The type is `[String: AnyObject]` and since the type is non optional there is no need to cast it.

The reason is that the mutable collection types `NSMutableArray` and `NSMutableDictionary` are not bridged automatically to the Swift counterparts.

Comment: If you had read the question you would have noticed this sentence: "I will workaround this by using directly a Swift Dictionnary but I would like to get the why of such a problem."

Comment: @AsTeR I don't think you'll get much help being so sharp with people.

Comment: I've added the reason.

Comment: @trojanfoe that's true, it's not against vadian it's more being tired that people answering for the sake of answering (that usually follow also the pattern of downvoting without commenting or request for closing without more reason).

Comment: @vadian thanks for the reason, and do you have any hints about what to do if you bump into the need of doing such a cast ?

Comment: The error message says that the types are not related so the best solution is to use the native Swift types as much as possible.